# How can I modify the scale in gnuplot to an arbitrary function?

Tags: gnuplot, scale

I'd like to have a logarithmic color bar like

### 1,
10^-2,
10^-4,
10^-6,
0 (or +-10^-8),
-10^-6,
-10^-4,
-10^-2,

all with the same spacing in between

but I couldn't find any commands for intenser modification of the scale.

Please send help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set arbitrary tic labels. Check `help cbtics` or `help xtics`.
That's what you have asked for, however, I assume you also want to plot some data.
What do you want to plot? A map, some function? How does your data look like?
Additionally, you have to define some mapping function for your data.

**Addition:**

This would be a possible (discontinuous) mapping function for mapping your values from `[-1:-1e-8]` to `[-1:0]` and from `[+1e-8:1]` to `[0:1]`, and values with `abs(value)<1e-8` to `NaN`.

```
f(x) = abs(x)<1e-8 ? NaN : sgn(x)*(1+log10(abs(x))/8)
```

**Code:**

```
reset session

set xrange[1e-10:1]
set logscale xy
set grid x,y

set cbrange[-1:1]

set cbtics("-1" -1, "-10^{-2}" -0.75, "-10^{-4}" -0.5, "-10^{-6}" -0.25, "0" 0, \
            "1"  1,  "10^{-2}"  0.75,  "10^{-4}"  0.5,  "10^{-6}"  0.25)

plot x lc palette
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! That's exactly what I wanted. I have already seen such a solution with the cbtics but I would have never gotten the idea that it works with logarthm going through zero too. I'll plot a map.

Comment: @Pia glad to hear. Now you have to find the mapping function. Mind that this function needs to map everything with absolute value `<1e-8` to `NaN`. You can use the ternary operator for this, check `help ternary`.